# How to get the selected option of a radion button element in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, radio-button, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-form-fieldset

In a `Fieldset` I have an `Element\Radio` `foo` and `Element\Text` `bar`.

```
public function init()
{
    $this->add(
        [
            'type' => 'radio',
            'name' => 'foo',
            'options' => [
                'label' => _('foo'),
                'value_options' => [
                    [
                        'value' => 'a',
                        'label' => 'a',
                        'selected' => true
                    ],
                    [
                        'value' => 'b',
                        'label' => 'b'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            ...
        ]);

    $this->add(
        [
            'name' => 'bar',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'bar',
                ...
            ],
            ...
        ]);
}
```

The validation of the field `bar` is depending on the selected `foo` option. It's easy to implement, if I can get the selected value of `foo`:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return [
        'bar' => [
            'required' => $this->get('foo')->getCheckedValue() === 'a',
            ...
        ],
    ];
}
```

But there is no method `Radio#getCheckedValue()`. Well, I can iterate over the  `$this->get('foo')->getOptions()['value_options']`, but is it really the only way?

How to get (in the `Fieldset#getInputFilterSpecification()`) the selected option of a `Zend\Form\Element\Radio`?

Answer (score 0):

The selected option gets POSTed to the server along with everything else from the HTML form and is all of this is available in validators through the `$context` array.
You can create a conditionally required field by using a callback validator and the `$context` array like this:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
    return [
        'bar' => [
            'required' => false,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'continue_if_empty' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Callback',
                    'options' => [
                        'callback' => function ($value, $context) {
                            return $context['foo'] === 'a'
                        },
                        'messages' => [
                            \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'This value is required when selecting "a".'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
```

That would check if 'foo' is equal to 'a', i.e. option 'a' is selected and return `true` when it is, which marks the input as valid, and `false` when it's not, marking the input invalid.